# Get the next child element in javascript whose innerHTML is dynamic value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a parent element with button & a child div in php code.The child div has innerHTML to be assigned dynamically and is also being displayed dynamically in output.

Php code:

```
$loc = $sdid;  /*get value according to some loop condition thus this value 
               changes as loop iterates*/        
echo '<div id="parent">
      <input type="button" id="investbutton" value="Invest" onclick="InputInvest()"> 
      <div id="child">'.$loc.'</div> 
      </div>';
```

Now the child has dynamic value of $loc variable.

On clicking the button,InputInvest() is called:

```
function InputInvest()
{
   var x=0;
   x= document.getElementById("investbutton").nextSibling.innerHTML;

   document.write(x);   
}
```

But the outpt is showing 'undefined'
How to solve this error?

**Edit:**
Solution to previous problem:

```
x = document.getElementById("investbutton").nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
```

Problem 2:
But now the output only the first for loop condition value..I think javascript is not able to reassign x as the values are definitely iterating properly...or may be the input tag is not able to take values dynamically.
Any new suggestions on this is welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)

```
x = document.getElementById("investbutton").nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
```

Because a line break would be considered as a `text node`. And it wont have a property called `innerHTML`.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xm7cbgyf/)

---

In **.php**,

```
<input type="button" class="investbutton" value="Invest" onclick="InputInvest(this)">
```

**JS**:

```
function InputInvest(_this) {
   var x = _this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
   document.write(x);   
}
```

Comment: This does solve the undefined condition problem...but now the output only the first for loop condition value..I think javascript is not able to reassign x as the values are definitely iterating properly...or may be the input tag is not able to take values dynamically

Comment: Why not use jQuery to get all siblings and then iterate over them or pick one?

Comment: @AishwaryaR Do you have more than one `investbutton` in your dom?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy  Yes!Suppose every loop displays an invest button and a value beside it then the same value is to be accessed.I even tried giving the value attribute of the invest button dynamic value but it only displays th first value every single time for any invest button.

Comment: @AishwaryaR The basic rule is that, Id should be unique. That is causing the problem in your case.

Comment: @Philip i am able to choose the required invst button...but the problem is i'm not able to dynamically send the corresponding value from the loop of that invest button to the javascript function

Comment: @AishwaryaR I just edited the answer. Can you check it now?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy It worked like a charm...Thanks a ton! Please can you tell me the effect of having the same id in this case.Why it did not work that way?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy  Yaa sure!

Comment: @AishwaryaR If you have same id for more than one elements, then when executing `document.getElementById("investbutton")` the first occurrence of the entire elements will be picked always.